# Developing iOS xcode that connects to codeigniter data

Tags: php, iphone, codeigniter

I have an existing web app that I have written in CodeIgniter using a MySQL database.

I now want to learn how to develop an iPhone app for the web app.

I have had a look at a lot of tutorials about xcode and iphone development but I have yet to see one about connecting and displaying data from my database.

I have seen the topic of RESTful come up a few times but am unsure if this is the direction I need to go?

If anyone has had success in building an iphone app that connects to a MySQL DB, would they be kind enough to share some tips or tuts on getting started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was working in a similar project: http://www.savemeeting.com It consists in an app (iOS, Android and Blackberry) and a Web showing the same information. Basically you need a Web Service (RESTful, XML-RPC, SOAP...) server and a Web Service client in your app.

I recomend you to write a RESTful server, if you use Code Igniter, you can use this library: https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver and then write the client in your iOS app (sorry, I have no knowledge to guide you in this part).

Comment: That is good advice.  Use Phil Sturgeon's class as a basis to create a RESTful sevice that returns json.  It is not difficult to do, and until CodeIgniter builds the RESTful architecture into the framework as an option, this is pretty much the standard.